# Can't compile a c++ "helloworld" with the gcc compiler on windows's codeblocks

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, codeblocks

Error message:

[image: The Codeblocks Error]

Compiler settings:

[image: The gcc Commpiler settings]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ codeblocks setup".

Comment: Please edit your post with the **text** output from CodeBlocks.

Comment: Please don't post an image of the error - post the actual text.  (I forgive the compiler settings, because that really is a gui)

Comment: Try opening up a command (console) window and running the compiler from the command line.  Get the command line working, then port it into CodeBlocks.

Comment: Note: This actually *is* the point of "Hello World"  it is *hard* to get it to compile - and the program is trivial so that you don't have difficulty with the program, just the setup.

Comment: Not familiar with your setup but have found other IDE's don't handle spaces in path names very well because some of the tools in the build chain see the spaces as separators between command line parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeblocks cannot find the MinGW compiler. Here are two possible solutions.

The first solution would be to download the MinGW compiler from here:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mingw.org%2Fdownload%2Finstaller&ts=1463193321&use_mirror=pilotfiber

After you have downloaded the compiler it should be installed directly to your C: drive on windows. Click on the "settings" drop-down menu. Click "Compiler" and enter the path of MinGW. Unfortunately it appears you already have done this and set it all up.

If you go to the Codeblocks download page here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/16.01/Windows/

You can download a version of Codeblocks that comes with the MinGW compiler and installs it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `C:\MinGW\bin` for the compiler's installation directory?